# WPF Binding two dependency Properties in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

i have a really annoying problem.

I declared two dependency properties in a custom control.

```
    /// Property for the color of the border
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LineColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LineColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(CCInputBox), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));
    public Brush LineColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(LineColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LineColorProperty, value); }
    }
```

And this  one

```
    /// Property for the color if the ui element is focused
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FocusColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(CCInputBox), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Gray));
    public Brush FocusColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(FocusColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FocusColorProperty, value); }
    }
```

Now i wanted to bind the LineColor to the FocusColor in the a controlTemplate trigger to show up the new LineColor when the UIElement is focused.

```
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="plcHolder" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="plcHolder" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter Property="LineColor" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=FocusColor}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

The triggers are working fine, just the lineColor property is set to his own default value which is black, and not to the FocusColor value.
Here is also the style i use for the UIElement where i set the FocusColor.

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type CCControls:CCInputBox}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="LineColor" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="FocusColor" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap" />
    <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource CCGrayBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CCInputBoxTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see any binding error in output window while debugging?

Comment: No, everything runs without any errors or warnings.